# How to achieve equivalent of take_while on a slice?

Tags: rust, slice

Rust slices do not currently support some iterator methods, i.e. take_while. What is the best way to implement take_while for slices?

```
const STRHELLO:&'static[u8] = b"HHHello";

fn main() {
    let subslice:&[u8] = STRHELLO.iter().take_while(|c|(**c=='H' as u8)).collect();
    println!("Expecting: {}, Got {}",STRHELLO.slice_to(3),subslice);
    assert!(subslice==STRHELLO.slice_to(3));
}
```

results in the error:

```
<anon>:6:74: 6:83 error: the trait `core::iter::FromIterator<&u8>` is not implemented for the type `&[u8]`
```

This code in the playpen:
http://is.gd/1xkcUa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, the issue you have is that `collect` is about creating a *new* collection, while a slice is about referencing a contiguous range of items in an existing array (be it dynamically allocated or not).

I am afraid that due to the nature of traits, the fact that the *original* container (`STRHELLO`) was a contiguous range has been lost, and cannot be reconstructed after the fact. I am also afraid that any use of "generic" iterators simply cannot lead to the desired output; the type system would have to somehow carry the fact that:

- the original container was a contiguous range
- the chain of operations performed so far conserve this property

This may be doable or not, but I do not see it done now, and I am unsure in what way it could be elegantly implemented.

---

On the other hand, you can go about it in the do-it-yourself way:

```
fn take_while<'a>(initial: &'a [u8], predicate: |&u8| -> bool) -> &'a [u8] { // '
    let mut i = 0u;
    for c in initial.iter() {
        if predicate(c) { i += 1; } else { break; }
    }
    initial.slice_to(i)
}
```

And then:

```
fn main() {
    let subslice: &[u8] = take_while(STRHELLO, |c|(*c==b'H'));
    println!("Expecting: {}, Got {}",STRHELLO.slice_to(3), subslice);
    assert!(subslice == STRHELLO.slice_to(3));
}
```

*Note: `'H' as u8` can be rewritten as `b'H'` as show here, which is symmetric with the strings.*

Comment: Man, great answer! In the time it took me to sit here and suspect that the answer might be something like this, you actually implemented it. Perhaps iter() on slices could instead return subslices containing a single item at a time, and then you could have something like collect that re-merges the redundant subslices?

Comment: @AndrewWagner: To be honest, I just don't know what the API could be here.

Comment: Still just spitballing, but if my general idea works, maybe all you need is each()? to generate the iterator, and maybe splice() to splice things back together?  maybe splice returns an iterator of slices for non-contiguous results...

Comment: @AndrewWagner: The idea of return an iterator of slices "as concatenated as possible" seems quite neat, in the absence of compile-time check.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible via some heavy gymnastics to implement this functionality using the stock iterators:

```
use std::raw::Slice;
use std::mem::transmute;

/// Splice together to slices of the same type that are contiguous in memory.
/// Panics if the slices aren't contiguous with "a" coming first.
/// i.e. slice b must follow slice a immediately in memory.
fn splice<'a>(a:&'a[u8], b:&'a[u8]) -> &'a[u8] {
    unsafe {
        let aa:Slice<u8> = transmute(a);
        let bb:Slice<u8> = transmute(b);
        let pa = aa.data as *const u8;
        let pb = bb.data as *const u8;
        let off = aa.len as int; // Risks overflow into negative!!!
        assert!(pa.offset(off) == pb, "Slices were not contiguous!");
        let cc = Slice{data:aa.data,len:aa.len+bb.len};
        transmute(cc)
    }
}

/// Wrapper around splice that lets you use None as a base case for fold
/// Will panic if the slices cannot be spliced!  See splice.
fn splice_for_fold<'a>(oa:Option<&'a[u8]>, b:&'a[u8]) -> Option<&'a[u8]> {
   match oa {
       Some(a) => Some(splice(a,b)),
       None => Some(b),
   }
}

/// Implementaton using pure iterators
fn take_while<'a>(initial: &'a [u8], 
                   predicate: |&u8| -> bool) -> Option<&'a [u8]> {
    initial
        .chunks(1)
        .take_while(|x|(predicate(&x[0])))
        .fold(None, splice_for_fold)
}
```

usage:

```
const STRHELLO:&'static[u8] = b"HHHello";
let subslice: &[u8] = super::take_while(STRHELLO, |c|(*c==b'H')).unwrap();
println!("Expecting: {}, Got {}",STRHELLO.slice_to(3), subslice);
assert!(subslice == STRHELLO.slice_to(3));
```

Matthieu's implementation is way cleaner if you just need take_while.  I am posting this anyway since it may be a path towards solving the more general problem of using iterator functions on slices cleanly.